# Best Partitioning Software

Tags: partition

Now that PartionMagic seems to have died, I was wondering, what do you guys think is the best Partition Software?

Comment: For what operating system/architecture?

Comment: I guess for each one? Right now I have Fedora and Windows 7 dual booted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GNU Parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/index.shtml). Or if you want a nice GUI, [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). A live/bootable CD image is available from the GParted folks. I've used these products many, many times in the past to create/extend/shrink/etc partitions both in Windows and linux systems, and have never had issues with data corruption. Usual caveats apply, though, for partition resize operations.